# Iterate through posts based on array of categories

Tags: php, loop

Is it possible to loop through posts based on an **array of categories**?

I would like to loop through an array of categories and then display those posts based on the category they are a part of. Posts can be part of two categories: ie. Category 1 and Category 2. Ideally posts from Category 1 would be in its own `<div>` and posts from Category 2 would be in its own `<div>`.

Instead, my code currently displays ALL posts from both category 1 and category 2.

```
<?php
$args  = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 25,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'category'        => array(11,16), 
    'post_type'       => 'page',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true );

    $posts = get_posts($args); 
        foreach ($posts as $post) :
        ?>
          <div class="category">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                  <div class="person">
                    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(array(200,200)); ?>
                    <p class="name"><?php echo the_title(); ?></p>
                  </div>
             </a>
          </div>
        <?php endforeach;
?>
```

What could I be missing? Thanks for your help!

P.S. I want to also make sure that this works for any number of categories that the user may add via the dashboard.